# Business Catalyst: Check if we are on the root URL with Liquid

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

I would like to use Liquid markup to test if the page that is being viewed is the home page (but specifically the root URL of a website), e.g. www.mysite.com/

I attempted to use {{globals.get}}, because according to the [BC Documentation](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/liquid/globals.html), this should output...

> **The current relative path** and the query parameters passed in the URL. For example, for the URL
>   http://mtica1.businesscatalyst.com/_s1/s2?a=1&b=2 the output of the
>   module is:

```
{
    "ID": "/_s1/s2",
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
}
```

[emphasis mine]

However, it appears that Business Catalyst does not deal with this Liquid tag consistently. On the site root `{{globals.get}}` outputs `{}` and on other system pages such as the eCommerce layouts, `ID` is replaced with `CatalogueID: "xxxxx"`, where xxxxx is the ID of the Catalogue, NOT the "current relative path" at all!

Needless to say, I was unable to output `ID: "/"` to target the site root as expected.

**How can I test if a user is on the root URL using Liquid?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: I have added another solution to the beginning of this answer but have left my original solution below so others can see the process I went through.**

While I have had no issues with the solution detailed below, due to "blank" being undocumented in BC, I would prefer a solution that does't have the potential to be broken if the BC Dev team make updates.

---

### NEW SOLUTION

**You can check if you are the site root using the following Liquid markup:**

```
    {module_pageaddress collection="page" template=""}
    {module_siteUrl collection="site" template=""}

    {% assign fullUrl = 'http://' | append: {{site.siteUrl}} | append: '/' -%}

    {% if page.pageUrl == {{fullUrl}} -%}

        // we are on the site root

    {% else -%}

        // we are not on the site root

    {% endif -%}
```

---

### PREVIOUS SOLUTION

**You can test if you are on the site root using the following Liquid markup:**

```
{% if globals.get == blank -%}
    // we are on the root URL - do something
{% else -%}
    // we are not on the root URL
{% endif -%}
```

The "key" piece of information here is the keyword **blank**.

I did a number of tests and discovered that the only page that outputs `{}` as a result of `{{globals.get}}` is the root URL. (**Note:** I have not tested this exhaustively - please comment if you find another page that outputs `{}`)

I tried `{% if globals.get == {} -%}` but this simply targets all pages because all of them have something output inside `{}`.

BC Documentation had nothing, but I found [this document](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/5c5e7de31e6d0da5529b642669343ab4b08afa4f/lib/liquid/context.rb#L139) which mentions it and surprise, surprise: it works.

Let's just hope the BC Dev team don't go and change something that stops this from working.

Comment: To date I have tested and the above works on the following: standard pages (incl the root URL with Google analytics in place), Blog Post List and Post layouts, Blog Tag and Archive pages, Online Store incl Catalogue and Product Layouts, Shopping Cart, Checkout and Receipt page, 404 page, Secure Zone Unauthorized, Secure Zone Access Denied, Password Retrieve Request, Password Retrieve Confirmation, Password Reset, Password Reset Success. Will update when I have more.

Answer (score -2):

that is not actually correct.
System pages and other pages through modules will also encounter that.
Globals.get is data and can occur on the home page through many different things like if you have google analytics or other 3rd party tracking, certain clicks through and more.
Unfortunately the above is a very inaccurate way to do that.

Could you explain what your goal is - Why you need this?

Comment: Your "answer" isn't actually an answer to the question and more of a comment on my answer. The reason for needing to check if we are on the root URL is irrelevant really isn't it? It's something I need to do for a project. Unfortunately the BC docs state that a certain tag will provide certain information when it is not the case. Consistent output of {{globals.get.ID}} should really result in either the ID number of every page or the URL of every page. Instead there is inconsistency - even the docs don't reflect what actually happens. Can you explain what is "not actually correct"?

Comment: I thought I did mark it as a comment. The reason to check is not irrelevant, it is the core and main aspect here more then anything else. Your creating a solution to problem or goal. What is that, you picked the right solution? Does not seem so. Globals.get Primary goal is url values but has a knock on effect in its output in terms of system ID's or other values depending on currently module or part of the site. As soon as you come from a google tracking link or google tracking values are amended to the URL and your above will fall over in such cases. And then with the

Comment: So with the above and inconsistency behaviors of BC will not work 60% of the time. It seems a very odd solution to a non obvious problem or goal. Knowing the goal is key. I very often find people are not aware of a BC output and come up with complex solutions when a tag or liquid output actually exists.

Comment: I don't think you can mark an answer as a comment. Only the other way around. Comments are all good but they should be made in the comments section.

Comment: Ok so go ahead and provide an answer to the question: "Check if we are on the root URL with Liquid". If you think this isn't possible, perhaps you would be so kind as to suggest an alternative. This is a question and answer site. All you have done so far is to tell me that my answer isn't any good. It works for me to date with the testing I have done. If you can provide a better answer to the question, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Like I said, the method wont work. There are plenty of ways to do it by getting the URL and counting how many / there are for example.
You can use this module for it:
http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/modules/pages/module_pageaddress.html
But still missing the critical goal of what your doing. Still betting there is something native or easier to achieve it - From experience with people using BC this is 90%+ the case when reading stuff like this.

Comment: Except that it does work. It's currently working without fault on a site of mine and I haven't managed to get it to not work yet. I think what I'm hearing you say is that there are better solutions. I just don't understand why you won't detail a better solution as an answer. If it's a better solution more ppl will vote for it (including myself) and it will become the accepted best answer.

Comment: Good luck to you then Luke. Tried to help. Cant offer a better solution if you wont say what your trying to do. Good luck, cant help if even with examples you do not understand why it wont work and if you wont believe me on how BC works, I cant help you.

Comment: I think you're reading me wrong. I'm trying to help as well. I can see that you're new to Stack Overflow. The purpose of this site is to provide specific answers to specific questions. I've asked a specific question: how can we use Liquid to find out whether we are on the site root URL? I want an if/else statement. This is all included above. The idea is that you provide a specific solution for this. You've said there are many ways to do it, but you have only hinted at them, rather than providing specific instructions, which is the point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Once you provided a specific solution, users (including myself) would vote on that solution. The best solutions get the most votes and are listed first. I don't know if you've seen my updated answer. Much of this comment thread really belongs as comments to my initial answer - your "answer" really should have been a comment on my question. You obviously have a v good understanding of BC. I don't understand why you wouldn't share that understanding in the form of a specific solution that you believe is the best way to achieve the goal: check if we are on the root URL using Liquid.

Comment: Until you provide a problem and what your trying to achieve. People cant. And wont! All I will say to people reading this.
I have shared the explanation, you either have ignored or not understanding the examples I gave to why it wont work. This is not on me Luke, its all you.

Choose to use the solution but it wont work properly folks.
The OP wont provide their goal for some strange reason and also does not understand the explanations on why it wont work, for others you should be able to see from my original comments and examples why.

Comment: Wow, ok then, an example of one of the many things I would try to achieve: display certain content on the home page only. Does that help you provide a solution? Don't tell me to use a separate template. Don't tell me to use JS. These are not the solutions I'm looking for. Does that help?

Comment: Which is exactly what I been asking all the time.
You know how easy that is with no extra template and so on. You got a variety of methods, no CSS no JS.
You can do proper logic data to your template at the top to do all manner of things you can control
You can use module_Data Templates and Pages for data use on projects
For things like page specific content you have module_pagename, module_pagetitle, module_pageaddress ALL of which can be passed as collections so as a liquid variable you can access to do what ever and you have all the base data liquid spits out and the globals.

Comment: So for that example, there are heaps of ways you can do something more robust, less effort, more reliable and cleaner. Like I said - Present the core goal and people may likely suggest root better solutions. Just be accommodating, only trying to help offer best solution. Can not do that without all the facts.

Comment: But Liam, you still haven't provided a specific solution. I hear you saying that there a wide variety of ways available, but you haven't specifically outlined any of them. That's the point of Stack Overflow. It's not to give a vague push in the right direction; it's to provide specific answers. Check out my updated solution using {module_pageaddress} and {module_siteurl}. Any good? If you think you can provide a better solution, do it! :) I'll mark it as correct! Promise! :)