# Create hreflang tags only using Liquid in Business catalyst

Tags: html, liquid, business-catalyst, hreflang

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to create hreflang tags, just using liquid in BC, without the need to create webapp.

I tried this way which makes sense, but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
{% capture pagURL -%}{module_pageaddress}{% endcapture -%}
{% if pagURL contains "http://us." -%}
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL}}" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://us', 'http://www' }}" hreflang="en-uk" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://us', 'http://au' }}" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://us', 'http://eu' }}" hreflang="en" />
{% elsif pagURL contains "http://au." -%}
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL}}" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://au', 'http://www' }}" hreflang="en-uk" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://au', 'http://us' }}" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://au', 'http://eu' }}" hreflang="en" />
{% elsif pagURL contains "http://eu." -%}
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL}}" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://eu', 'http://us' }}" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://eu', 'http://au' }}" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://eu', 'http://www' }}" hreflang="en-uk" />
{% elseif pagURL contains "http://www." -%}
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL}}" hreflang="en-uk" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://us' }}" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://au' }}" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://eu' }}" hreflang="en" />
{% else -%}
{% endif  -%}
```

The weird part is, the following it works on that same page.

```
{% capture pagURL -%}{module_pageaddress}{% endcapture -%}
{{ pagURL}}<br>
{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://us' }}<br>
{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://au' }}<br>
{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://eu' }}<br>
```

And this also works

```
{{ pagURL | replace: 'http://www', 'http://us' | prepend: '<link rel="alternate" href="' | append: '" hreflang="en-us" />' }}
```

The shorter the code the better of course.

Comment: The code actually works perfectly on every page, except for the homepage.

Comment: Just a question: is there a reason that "pagURL" and "elsif" missing an "e"?

Comment: ''pagURL'' is a variable, it is declared with ''capture'' , ''elsif'' is the correct way of writing "else if" in liquid, BC.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't read the capture statement properly. And wasn't aware of elsif. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Daut, you're going to love this! ;p

I ran into similar obstacles when working on a solution for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842062/business-catalyst-check-if-we-are-on-the-root-url-with-liquid/). (I'll explain below).

As far as I can tell, BC has some issues around its rendering of Liquid when it comes to URLs and variables. I don't really understand the ins and outs of Liquid in terms of the server-side processing but things do not appear to work as they should in BC.

For example, if we take your code and strip it back to its bare essentials:

**This** (whether inserted into the `<head>` or `<body>`) **DOESN'T work:**

```
    {% capture pagURL -%}
        {module_pageaddress}
    {% endcapture -%}    

    <link rel="alternate" href="{{pagURL}}" hreflang="en-us">
```

It outputs `<link rel="alternate" href="{{pagURL}}" hreflang="en-us">`, `{{pagURL}}` being the literal text that is rendered.

**But this DOES work:**

```
    {% capture pagURL -%}
        {module_pageaddress}
    {% endcapture -%}     

    {% assign test = '<link rel="alternate" href="' | append: {{pagURL}} | append: '" hreflang="en-us">' -%}

    {{test}}
```

---

Compare the above to the issues I ran into.

**This DOESN'T work:**

```
    {module_pageaddress collection="page" template=""}
    {module_siteUrl collection="site" template=""}

    {% assign fullUrl = "http://{{site.siteUrl}}/" -%}

    {% if page.pageUrl == {{fullUrl}} -%}

        // We are on the home page

    {% else -%}

        // We are not on the home page

    {% endif -%}
```

The problem here is `{{site.siteUrl}}` inside the variable declaration. Not sure what the issue is but it just can't handle the jandle.

**But this DOES work:**

```
    {module_pageaddress collection="page" template=""}
    {module_siteUrl collection="site" template=""}

    {% assign fullUrl = 'http://' | append: {{site.siteUrl}} | append: '/' -%}

    {% if page.pageUrl == {{fullUrl}} -%}

        // We are on the home page

    {% else -%}

        // We are not on the home page

    {% endif -%}
```

---

And finally getting back to your example, (ironically) **this works:**

```
    {% capture pagURL -%}
        {module_pageaddress}
    {% endcapture -%}

    <a href="{{pagURL}}">test</a>
```

Go figure.

I'm pretty sure that BC has some automatic way of grabbing head elements contained anywhere on a page and re-inserting them into the head (even if they were inserted into the head to begin with).

I wonder if that causes problems in cases like `<link rel="alternate" href="{{pagURL}}" hreflang="en-us">`. It doesn't explain the issue I ran into though.

End of the day, I think there are still some big issues with BC's implementation of Liquid.

Comment: Hey Luke, I know all that you say is true, and I appreciate your help, but my code is still 30 lines :D . This is a great answer, but my question is how to make it short.

Comment: Totally - sorry I didn't miss that but I forgot to address it in my answer. In the end my goal became simply to find a way of getting your link tags to actually work. At this stage I'd be looking at how to get the entire original setup to work before trying to shorten. Converting all your link tags (or parts of link tags) to variables may still shorten your overall code.